# Is it possible for 2 threads to select/insert data from/to the same sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible for 2 threads to select or insert data in same sqlite database on Android?

Answer (score 0):

If they'll try to write something simultaneously, than, I think, you'll get errors.
Not to mention conflicts, if 2 thread will try to change the same data.

I think the better solutions would be 1 manager that writes to the database, and queue of actions, that must be executed by this manager.

You can have some kind of listener for this queue, that will notify the manager, that new actions are awaiting for processing, so you won't need to implement a timer, or something for checking the queue continuously.

Comment: But if I will create 2 managers: one just for insert and one just for select: each of them will get a reference to same database. It should work if one thread will insert something and the other thread will get some data from database?

Comment: Might work in your case, but you should test it good. Anyway, it's a dodgy tactic for my taste. Don't really know how android sqlite works, but I'm sure writable database instance locks the database for any other write access (might work for read only). And I think some issues might popup, when writable instance still hasn't commited some changes, but readable tries to read them (and as a result, gets the older version. Not up to date)
I say, use it only if you really need so.